# Use Controls Of Another Form

Tags: delphi, forms, lazarus

I have a project on Lazarus that have two Forms, `FormMain` and `OutputForm`. I want to show a output on `OutputMemo` at the second Form with this code:

```
procedure FormMain.ShowButton(Object: Sender);
begin 
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then 
    AProcess := TProcess.Create(nil); 
  AProcess.CommandLine := 'gcc.exe ' + SaveDialog1.FileName + ' -o ' TextField23.Text; 
  AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit, poUsePipes]; 
  AProcess.Execute; 

  OutputForm.OutputMemo.Lines.BeginUpdate; 
  //OutputForm.OutputMemo.Lines.Clear; 
  OutputForm.OutputMemo.Lines.LoadFromStream(AProcess.Output); 
  OutputForm.OutputMemo.Lines.EndUpdate; 

  AProcess.Free; 
end;
```

But when I try to compile this code, I got the error:

> Identifier not found "OutputForm"

At the top of OutputForm unit I have:

```
unit Output;
```

And when I try to call it from FormMain unit(`OutputForm: Output;`) I got this error:

> Error in type definiition

What I have to do?

Comment: try adding the unit of the OutputForm to the uses clause.

Comment: Nathan, once you get this compiling, please make sure you test the case where you *cancel* the "Save" dialog. Editing your question to improve the code indentation caused me to notice the logic error for that use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RRUZ said, you need a reference to the unit where OutputForm is declared.  Here's the basic idea:

Each form has a form declaration file (DFM in Delphi; I think Lazarus calls them LFMs) and a corresponding Object Pascal unit file (.PAS) where you put their code.  This is a normal **unit** file like any other, as far as the compiler's concerned.  The only difference is that it has a form associated with it.

Open the code for OutputForm and look at the top.  It'll say something like "unit OutputForm;"  Copy the unit name, and paste it into the **uses** clause of FormMain's unit, and then it should work.

**EDIT:**  Not quite sure what you're trying to do with that edit, but you don't need to redeclare OutputForm.  It should already be declared as a global variable in the Output unit.  You just need to add Output to your uses clause, so you'll end up with something similar to this:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  Output; //on a separate line to show it's not a system lib

type
  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
  ...
```

Comment: Take a look at the question now please.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, isn't "output" a reserved word in Pascal?

Comment: I am suggesting a possible answer. I don't know enough about Lazarus to know whether this is the case.